# Как в PyQt5 Python в одном блоке setStyleSheet прописать дизайн для нескольких кнопок?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

У меня есть много виджетов которые нужно изменять в соответствии с условиями. Стало интересно возможно ли объеденить действия.

Comment: Стили кнопок занести в словарь/список, затем можно использовать цикл.

Comment: Да Вы гений сэр.

Comment: ваш вопрос не очень понятен, о каких условиях и действиях вы говорите. Приведите пожалуйста [mcve] и лучше расскажите, что вы хотите сделать.